# Javascript Calculation Using For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm sure that this is simple, but the solution is eluding me. I want to write a function that will result in: 1000 + 1001 + 1002 + 1003 + 1004 (so I'll output 5010)

I have a form where the user inputs a number x (1000 in this case) and a number of times it will iterate y (5 in this case)

I know that I need to store the value each time through in var total, but I'm not quite getting it.

I have this so far:

```
function baleTotal(){
  var x = document.addBale.strt.value;
  var y = document.addBale.baleNum.value;
  var calc = Number(x);
  total = 0;

  for (var y; y > 0; y--) {
   calc++;
  }              

  document.addBale.result.value = total;
}
```

Comment: `for (var y; y > 0; y--)` <--- what's this?

Comment: You increment calc in your loop but do nothing with it.

Comment: Right, I had been setting the output value to calc, which gave me 1005 , which is just the iteration. I need to do something like total = total + calc, but I've tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually adding to your total.
This does the calculation given the base and the number of iterations and returns the result, rather than operating directly on the DOM.

```
function baleTotal(base, iterations) {
    var total = 0;
    for (i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
        total += (base + i);
    }
    return total;
}

console.log(baleTotal(1000, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything with total and also you are redeclaring y. Try this:

```
function baleTotal(){
  var x = document.addBale.strt.value;
  var y = document.addBale.baleNum.value;
  var calc = Number(x);
  total = 0;

  for (; y > 0; y--) {
   total += calc + y;
  }              

  document.addBale.result.value = total;
}
```

Not tested but should work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this more or less what you mean?

```
function baleTotal(){
  var x = document.addBale.strt.value;
  var y = document.addBale.baleNum.value;
  total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < y; i++) {
   total += x + i;
  }             

  document.addBale.result.value = total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
function baleTotal(){
  total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < document.addBale.baleNum.value; ++i) {
    total += document.addBale.strt.value + i;
  }
  document.addBale.result.value = total;
}
```